# Nokogiri get element which attribute match a pattern

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri, screen-scraping

I'm trying to guess price from an HTML.

If #id or .class or direct parent has attribute value like some regex =~ [price.*|prdown|proff]+

1) Does Nokogiri doc.css accept regex like jsoup Java library does? i.e. [attr~=regex] https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html

2) Can I accomplish that passing regex as argument for the attribute value? instead of creating a custom function?

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url).read)

  def get_price(doc)
    if doc.at_css("meta[itemprop='price']")
      price = doc.css("meta[itemprop='price']").first.attributes["content"]
    elsif doc.at_css('.price')
      price = doc.at_css('[class~=price]').text
    else
     price = ''
    end
    /([\d|\.|\$]+)/.match(price)[1].gsub(/[\.|\$]+/, '')
  end
```

Comment: [Nokogiri Docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri%2FXML%2FSearchable%3Acss) seems like it would appropriately answer this question

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Nokogiri has provision for you to create your own `search`, `css`, `xpath`, `at`, `at_css` or `at_xpath` functions.

It's in the [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) and [Nokogiri::XML::Searchable](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable#search-instance_method) documentation. For instance:

> Custom XPath functions and CSS pseudo-selectors may also be defined. To define custom functions create a class and implement the function you want to define. The first argument to the method will be the current matching NodeSet. Any other arguments are ones that you pass in. Note that this class may appear anywhere in the argument list. For example:

```
node.search('.//title[regex(., "\w+")]', 'div.employee:regex("[0-9]+")'
  Class.new {
    def regex node_set, regex
      node_set.find_all { |node| node['some_attribute'] =~ /#{regex}/ }
    end
  }.new
)
```